# AWS Amplify.SignIn Network error on Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using sign in from Amplify like this (inside an async handle function on a button click):

```
const res = await Auth.signIn({
  username: 'my@email.com',
  password: '123456'
});
```

I get on Chrome network:

[image]

My doubt is this, I'm using the same Amplify config that is already working with a mobile app, but now in a web page, in other words, I'm using have configured:

```
const amplifyConfig = {
  Auth: {
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AMPLIFY_AUTH_REGION,
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMPLIFY_AUTH_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMPLIFY_AUTH_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AMPLIFY_AUTH_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID
  }
};

Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
```

Where each `REACT_APP` value is the same in both the app mobile and now in the web where I have the error.
Should I use another USER_POOL for the web and another for the app? they both will use the same Cognito users...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with refreshing the page on the submit button. Maybe [this](https://www.radishlogic.com/aws/aws-cognito/how-to-fix-network-error-on-aws-cognito/) will help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).